# How to control which function is applied as values are iterated over, given changes of a corresponding variable

Tags: python, logic

This is really just a simple logic question, but I provide a concrete example.

By 'corresponding' variable, I mean a variable that is understood to be related to the underlying data, although the value of the variable is not important for my question, just the fact the variable changes is important.

The code below generates the lists...

A = [2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3]

B = [3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2]

...by responding to a change in the values in the 'slope' list. But, actually this should be...

A = [2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2]

B = [3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3]

What is the logic required to correct this?

```
def funcOne(val):
    return val + 1

def funcTwo(val):
    return val + 2

values = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
slope = [1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1]

A = []
B = []
l = len(values)

for i in range(l-1):
    val = values[i]
    sign = slope[i]
    pre = slope[i-1]
    nex = slope[i+1]
    
    if pre == sign:
        va = funcOne(val)
        vb = funcTwo(val)
        A.append(va)
        B.append(vb)
    if nex != sign:
        va = funcOne(val)
        vb = funcTwo(val)
        A.append(vb)
        B.append(va)
    
print(A)
# target list:
# [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2]

print(B)
# target...
# [3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
def funcOne(val):
    return val + 1

def funcTwo(val):
    return val + 2

values = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
slope = [1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1]

A = []
B = []
l = len(values)

for i in range(l-1):
    val = values[i]
    sign = slope[i] 
    pre = slope[i-1]
    nex = slope[i+1]

    if sign == pre:
        va = funcOne(val)  
        vb = funcTwo(val)   
        A.append(va)
        B.append(vb)
    if pre > nex:
        va = funcOne(val)
        vb = funcTwo(val)
        A.append(vb)
        B.append(va)
print(A)
# target list:
# [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2]

print(B)
# target...
# [3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I have a working solution I see in fact the correct behaviour would result in the lists

A = [2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2], and

B = [3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3].

This has been corrected in the original post.

Overall, irrespective of the exact behaviour required, I have found that a solution to this problem is to create and update a variable that represents which function was applied in the previous step (in this case simply a boolean called 'check'), to evaluate against whether the sign of the corresponding variable ('slope') is positive, negative or zero, and to evaluate against whether or not the corresponding variable is the same as in the previous step.

I feel like there must still be a more concise way of expressing this solution so additional comments are welcomed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def funcOne(val):
    return val + 1

def funcTwo(val):
    return val + 2

values = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
slope = [1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1]

A = []
B = []
l = len(values)

check = True

#for i in range(l-1):
for i in range(l):
    val = values[i]
    sign = slope[i] 
    pre = slope[i-1]    
    va = funcOne(val)  
    vb = funcTwo(val) 
        
    if sign == pre and check == True:
        A.append(va)
        B.append(vb)
        check = True
    if sign == pre and check == False:
        A.append(vb)
        B.append(va)
        check = False
    if sign != pre and sign > 0 and check == True:
        A.append(va)
        B.append(vb)
        check = True
    if sign != pre and sign > 0 and check == False:
        A.append(vb)
        B.append(va)
        check = False
    if sign != pre and sign < 0 and check == True:
        A.append(vb)
        B.append(va)
        check = True
    if sign != pre and sign < 0 and check == False:
        A.append(va)
        B.append(vb)
        check = False
    if sign != pre and sign == 0 and check == True:
        A.append(va)
        B.append(vb)
        check = True
    if sign != pre and sign == 0 and check == False:
        A.append(vb)
        B.append(va)
        check = False
         
print(A)
# [2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2]

print(B)
# [3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3]
```